# Traceability of a mature tree to its original seed via DNA

Tags: species-identification, dna

Is it possible to trace a specific seed to a fully mature tree?  For example, Can a seed be traced to the full-grown plant based on DNA?  Would it be possible for me to catalog a seed DNA and then years later be able to identify the full-grown plant to that seed that was cataloged?

Comment: I'd think it would be difficult to obtain the seed DNA without killing the seed.

Comment: Apart from the difficulty pointed out by @mgkrebbs, this is no different from the use of the DNA in forensic science... of course, if we are sure that the seed contains only one type of DNA.

Comment: @mgkrebbs — That really depends on the size of the seed — I worked in a maize lab and we regularly removed a small portion of the scutellum for genetic or other analyses (this can however impair seed viability). So, this could be done easily for trees with a large seed (e.g. nuts), but would be much more challenging for the many trees with tiny seeds. WesleyRios — you would need to determine viability over time after sampling to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

As [the embryo of a seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed#Embryo) typically contains many cells, it should in theory be possible to obtain DNA from a seed without disrupting it (there may be pragmatic issues with protocol, depending on the particulars of the seed).

If you have the DNA and each seed has been produced by a separate fertilization event, then each seeds DNA would be unique and it should certainly be possible to identify an individual genetically, just like it is with animals.

Not all seeds are genetically distinct however. For example, many plants will also produce seeds asexually under appropriate conditions, a process known as [apomixis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apomixis). If the seeds are being produced asexually, then your only hope would be to identify different mutations in different seeds, which is a much fainter signal and likely to fail for your intended purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When you say "separate fertilization event", what do you exactly mean by it pragmatically speaking?   For example, if I have a tree that produces the seed during a specific time of the year, would that mean that the seeds for that season are part of the same fertilization event?  Hence, the DNA for all the seeds would be the same?    I appreciate the education.  Thanks again

Comment: Plant reproduce sexually by combining [gametes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamete#Plants), just like we do. In the case of a plant, the male gamete is pollen and the female gamete is called the ovule, which is analogous to an egg. So during sexual reproduction, your typical tree gets "pregnant" with massive amounts of "fraternal twin" seeds, each produced by a different grain of pollen meeting a different ovule.

Comment: @jakebeal: It also seems possible (theoretically: I don't know whether it really happens) that one pollen+ovule fertilization could produce many seeds.  E.g. in many plants we see individual seed capsules containing many seeds in a regular pattern.  If each one required a separate pollen grain, you'd expect randomness, no?

Comment: @jamesqf Surprisingly, no! For plants with seeds in a regular pattern, the ovules generally develop in a regular pattern, each putting up its own receptor for pollen (though these are often bundled together also). Corn is a particularly good example: each thread of [corn silk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corn_silk) leads to a separate ovule, which will be separately pollinated and become a separate kernel. It's biology, so there are probably exceptions, but in general it seems that flowering plants pollinate their seeds separately.

Comment: @WesleyRios, the implications of the above is that most every tree seed will be genetically unique.  You cannot tell from the offspring-tree's DNA what time of year its seed was produced, nor what year.  With significant effort in advance, you might be able to determine which two trees were the parent trees if you collect the DNA of each of the potential parent trees (which usually would be large number) before they die.